# Declaring static list of strings and accessing by names

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

I want to be able to declare a static list of strings in VB.NET like this:

```
Public Class AccessTypes   
 Public Shared ViewRights As String = "viewrights"   
 Public Shared EditRights As String = "editrights"
End Class
```

Then, in a function I want to pass AccessType as a parameter like this:

```
Public Shared Function CheckAccess(ByVal AccessType As String) As Boolean
'-- check access code
'-- return true/false
End Function
```

When checking access, I can pass:

```
CheckAccess(AccessTypes.ViewRights)
```

but I can also pass:

```
CheckAccess("randomstring")
```

Is there a way that I can only pass one of the members of AccessType Class and not just any random string.

I know there is something terribly wrong with the above code. Any advise would be helpful.

Comment: @Plutonix this is not a duplication of the question you gave.

Comment: The question referred in duplicate does not talk about restricting value passed to the function as subset of the class. I want to be able to use CheckAccess(AccessTypes.ViewRights) and also CheckAccess(AccessTypes.EditRights) at different places.

Comment: Public Shared Function CheckAccess(ByVal xAccess As AccessTypes) As boolean

Comment: It absolutely shows how to limit arguments to a certain type.  `As String` means any string, `As Test` in the dupe or whatever you name it does exactly that.

Comment: @Plutonix definitely not, I suggest you read the question slowly and see the clear relevant differences.